# review A and prev B with python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table

```
df= pd.DataFrame ({'A': [0,1.5,2.1,2.9,4], 'B': [1.5,2.05,3,4,5]})
```

[image]

here I have 2 problems, a gap and an overlapping, I would like to detect automatically using python pandas, someone can help me, thanks

```
df= pd.DataFrame ({'A': [0,1.5,2.1,2.9,4], 'Validate': [1.5,2.05,3,4,5], 'test': ['np.nan', np.nan, 'gab','over', np.nan]})
```

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
s = df.B.shift() - (df.A)

df['Validate'] = np.select((s>0, s<0), ('over', 'gap'), default=np.nan)
```

Output:

```
     A     B Validate
0  0.0  1.50      nan
1  1.5  2.05      nan
2  2.1  3.00      gap
3  2.9  4.00     over
4  4.0  5.00      nan
```

Answer (score 1):

We can using `sign` from `numpy`

```
df['Validate']=np.sign(df.B.shift().sub(df.A)).map({1:'over',-1:'gap'})
df
Out[150]: 
     A     B Validate
0  0.0  1.50      NaN
1  1.5  2.05      NaN
2  2.1  3.00      gap
3  2.9  4.00     over
4  4.0  5.00      NaN
```